# Highcharts.js DateTime on x axis coming from JSON only displays number

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetime, highcharts

I'm struggling with a simple line graph with highcharts.js.
I have some json data coming in from an asp.net mvc controller:

```
public JsonResult GetSensorLineData(string SensorName)
    {
        List<SensorMeasurement> result= this.SQLSensorMeasuresRepository.FindAllMeasurements(SensorName).ToList();

        List<string> days = new List<string>();
        List<decimal> values = new List<decimal>();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            values.Add(item.Value);
            days.Add(item.DateTime.ToString());
        }

        dynamic data = new
        {
            Categories=days,
            Values = values
        };

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my cshtml file I'm doing this:

```
 homeDataService.init('@this.BaseUrl()');

        homeDataService.getTemperatureLineData("Roomtemperature", function myfunction(data) {
            var dataCategories=[];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.Categories.length; i++) {
                var strVal = data.Categories[i];
                var dateTimeParts = strVal.split(" ");
                var datePart = dateTimeParts[0];
                var timePart = dateTimeParts[1];

                var dateParts = datePart.split(".");
                var timeParts = timePart.split(":"); //german DateTime String coming from ASP.NET


                var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0], timeParts[0], timeParts[1]);
                data.Categories[i]=(date.getTime());

            }
            var chart;
            $('#temperature-line').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    categories:data.Categories,
                    minorTickInterval: 10,
                    minTickInterval:10,

                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature'
                    }
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Temperature',
                    data: data.Values
                }]
            });

        });
```

As you can see I'm transforming the german datetime so that highcharts can interpret it. However it doesn't. I only get this output:
[image]

UPDATE:
Ok now I'm returning from the Controller:

[image]

and I changed the chart code to (see below) but when I run this the browser just hangs. What am I doing wrong?

```
var chart;
            $('#temperature-line').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'

                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature'
                    }
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Temperature',
                    data: data
                }]
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a datetime axis and categories together - it's strictly one or the other for axis type.

You will need to either remove the categories, and send your timestamps as your data x values, or format the dates the way you want them displayed and use them as categories.

If you are displaying time series data, it always makes more sense to use the datetime values instead of categories.

Comment: Updated the question, now I think the data is OK but the browser crashes when I run the page.

Comment: It works now, thank you for the info! Now I need to find a way that the chart does not show every tooltip point on the line, too many values!

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

Datetime.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds

```
 var StatusOK = from u in counters
     where u.StatusID == 1
     select new { x = LogDate.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds, y = u.CountOK };

return jScript.Serialize(counters.ToArray());
```

or

```
(DateTime.Now-new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

and set in Highcharts for compatible with .NET Datetime Type:

```
  Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: { useUTC: true } });
```

and set xAxis in Highcharts :

```
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 100, 
        maxZoom:  60 
    },
```

Comment: I don't see how this will ever work for more than charting a single day, you are stripping of the Date part by calling TimeOfDay property...

Comment: You Can Use [**Data Grouping**](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping) For this Solution.

Comment: It's still only going to give you a 24 hour span.

Comment: I Think you should Set [turboThreshold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463506/highcharts-doesnt-display-series-with-lots-of-data-points/12468746#12468746) Properties